# Fetch RSS image in Email using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, rss

I am trying to pull RSS feed in email and I only manage to fetch title, description & link but I couldn't able to fetch the image URL, maybe because it's enclosed within `<media:content>` tag. I believe there is a way to call the values within this tag as I do for the rest of it.

It would be great if you can help me get the Image URL.

Here is the feed URL - https://www.oberlo.com/blog/feed

Here is the code I use

```
<div>

%%[

var @xml, @isXML, @nodes, @rowCount
Set @xml = HTTPGet("https://www.oberlo.com/blog/feed", false, 0, @CallStatus)

output(concat("<br>Call Status: ", @CallStatus))

if indexOf(@xml,"<channel>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/rss/channel/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

  output(concat("<br>rowCount: ", @rowCount))


  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to 5 do

      var @title
      var @description
      var @link
      var @Image

      set @nodepath = concat("/rss/channel/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"))) > 0 then
          set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"))) > 0 then
          set @description = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"))) > 0 then
          set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"),0),1),'Value')
      endif



      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath, 'Image'))) > 0 then

          set @Image = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"Image"),0),1),'image/jpeg')
      endif



      ]%%


       <h4>First Title - %%=v(@title)=%%</h4>

         Description - %%=v(@description)=%%
         <br>Link - <a href="%%=redirectto(@link)=%%">%%=v(@link)=%%</a>

          <br>Image - %%=v(@Image)=%%



      %%[

    next @i

  else

   outputline(concat("<br>no items found"))

  endif

else

  outputline(concat("<br>no XML found"))

endif

]%%

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're confident that the `media:content` node will always be an image, you could try isolating the namespace prefix (or replace it all with a custom unique name, e.g., `<mediacontentimg`):

```
Set @xml = Replace(
  HTTPGet("https://www.oberlo.com/blog/feed", false, 0, @CallStatus),
  '<media:content',
  '<media'
)
```

Then use the `media` node's `url` attribute (you can do this by appending "_att" to the attribute name):

```
if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath, 'media'))) > 0 then
  set @Image = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"media"),0),1),'url_att')
endif
```

You can now use the `url` attribute value in an `img` tag:

```
Image - <img src="%%=v(@Image)=%%">
```

Comment: It works perfect, thank you :)